# What is the most rigorous definition of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition

Is matrix just a rectangular array of symbols and expressions, or one can define it in a more formal way?

Comment: Real matrices are rectangular ($2$ dimensional) array of real numbers, equipped with addition and multiplication operators  $(\text{matrix},\text{matrix}) \to \text{matrix}$  (with vectors being $n\times 1$ matrices). Matrices are a particular case of the more general [tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) which are $k$ dimensional arrays, sort of matrix of matrices, capable of linear transforming matrices themselves.

Comment: An element of the matrix space.

Comment: I find it remarkable that the answers differ in the origin of the matrix' elements ([commutative] ring [with identity] or field)...

Comment: Unfortunately, no one can be *told* what a matrix is. You have to see it for yourself.

Comment: Many of the answers use notation that implies the matrix has finite dimensions. That is a rather simple (but very useful in practice!) special case of the general concept. For an uncountably infinite matrix (or underlying mathematical object) using notation like $\{1, 2, 3, \dots\}$ doesn't necessarily make any sense at all.

Comment: @alephzero Indeed, in Metamath we prefer to not assume an ordering on the index set, so the index set is allowed to be any finite set. However, there are difficulties with having a useful multiplication operation on infinite index sets (without assuming additional e.g. topological structure on the base ring and/or restricting to special subsets of the function space such as row/column-finite matrices), so we restrict to finite sets. (One automatically has an $R$-module structure on matrices, finite or infinite, because they are a special kind of function space.)

Comment: Note Stubborn says "symbols and expressions"... Yes, indeed, we may talk about matrices where the entries are not numbers.

Comment: @user1952009: real or complex.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Let $I_n:=\{1,\cdots, n\}$.

A $n \times m$-matrix with coefficients in a ring $\mathcal{R}$ is a function $a: I_n \times I_m \to \mathcal{R}$. We define $a_{i,j}:=a(i,j)$.

In other words, a rectangular array.

Sidenote: In my point of view, I think it is particularly useful to see the above definition as a *model* for the concept of a matrix, and retain subconsciously the relevant idea of a rectangular array as the core concept. If you truly understand the core concept and has relative comfort with mathematics, coming up with the above definition is a simple matter.

Comment: And when we would have $ a: I_n \times I_m \times I_p\times I_r \to\mathcal{R}$ we still have a matrix  or something other?

Comment: @Widawens I would call that a "multidimensional array", and definitely not a "tensor", although such an object is often called a "tensor" in machine learning contexts.

Comment: @littleO  and operations on such M.arrays could be similar to that on matrices ? With addition certainly there is no problem, but multiplication ??

Comment: @Widawens There is no standard way to define multiplication of higher-dimensional arrays anymore. The point is that a matrix can  be used to model a linear map, and multiplication of matrices just corresponds to function composition. There is no similar interpretation readily available for higher dimension arrays. (They can be used to model multilinear forms, however, similarly to the way a matrix can be used to model a bilinear form.)

Comment: @Widawens Matrix multiplication is, basically, tensor product followed by contraction (keeping in mind that a matrix is *not* a tensor - it *can* be one if we fix a basis). The same operations can be done for multidimensional arrays of any dimension (still pretending them to be tensors), but there appears a choice in indices for the contraction.

Comment: A problem with this definition is that the map $\emptyset\to\mathcal R$ is at the same time a $n\times 0$ matrix for any $n\in\Bbb N$ and a $0\times m$ matrix for any $m\in\Bbb N$. This is problematic when trying to define the matrix product of an  $n\times 0$ matrix with a $0\times m$ matrix, in other words of that map with itself.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: to me, that doesn't sound more problematic than the fact that you cannot divide by zero.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I don't see what you mean. Are you saying that with matrices you "cannot multiply by the empty matrix"? If so that seems like an artificial and unnecessary restriction, quite unlike the case with fields where division by zero is denied out of necessity. I believe Marc's point is the following: suppose $\circ$ is a function which performs multiplication on $\cal R$-matrices. What is $\emptyset\circ\emptyset$? The obvious answer is $\emptyset$, but this gives the wrong result for an $n\times 0$ matrix times a $0\times m$ matrix, which should be an $n\times m$ matrix of $0$'s.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: why? To me, it's like saying that $\frac{1/0}{1/0}=1$. Where would the zeroes in your $n\times m$ matrix come from? The matrices in the product have no entries.

Comment: @MartinArgerami In the standard definition of matrix multiplication, $C_{ik}=\sum_jA_{ij}B_{jk}$, here $i$ ranges over $\{1,\dots,n\}$, $k\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ and $j\in\{1,\dots,0\}=\emptyset$. Since the sum over $j$ is empty, the result is $0$ for each $i,k$, and $C$ is thus filled as an $m\times n$ matrix of zeroes. (Note that since we already declared that an $m\times p$ matrix times a $p\times n$ matrix gives an $m\times n$ matrix, we are forced to have $C$ as a nonempty matrix even if $p=0$.)

Comment: @MartinArgerami: I discussed this in my own answer to this question. The matrix product in question computes the composition of (zero) linear maps $K^m\to K^0\to K^n$, which is a bona fide zero map $K^m\to K^n$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: this answer is unproblematic as a definition of $i \times j$ matrices for given $i,j$.  Your objection isn’t a problem with this definition; rather, it shows that when you define the total set/space of all matrices, with $i,j$ varying, one must take a *disjoint union* $\coprod_{i,j} M_{i,j}$, not just a plain union $\bigcup_{i,j} M_{i,j}$.  [Edit: ah, I see Mario already mentioned this in comments on your answer.]

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Can the geometrical interpretation of matrices and its relation with complex numbers be of any help while understanding the core concept and possibly while defining matrices?

Comment: I think that it is important to include the algebra structure in the definition. That is multiplication and addition.

Answer (score 13):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, and $n,m$ be positive integers. The set of $n\times m$ matrices $R^{n\times m}$ is defined as an $R$-module (vector space, if $R$ is a field) freely generated by elements $\{e_{i,j}\}$, where $1\leq i \leq n$ and $1 \leq j   \leq m$. The element $e_{i,j}$ represents the matrix with all entries equal to zero, except the entry in $i$-th row and $j$-th column, which is equal to one.

For example, for $n=5, m=6$

$$e_{2,4}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Any matrix is a linear combination of $e_{i,j}$, with the coefficients being just the matrix entries.

This is still just an $n \times m$-dimensional $R$-module, but there is also a natural multiplication map $\times : R^{n\times m} \times R^{m \times p} \rightarrow R^{n \times p}$, defined by $$e_{i,j} \times e_{k,l} = \begin{cases} e_{i,l} & j = k \\ 0 & j \neq k \end{cases}$$ and extended by linearity. In fact, it is the standard matrix product.

In case $n=m$, this multiplication makes $R^{n\times n}$ into an $R$-algebra, isomorphic to the algebra of all endomorphisms on $R^n$.

Comment: This is the best answer, by far. But I'd denote $e_{i,j}$ by $E_{i,j}$ and I'd put a big matrix in the answer somewhere that has precisely one $1$ in it, with all the other entries $0$, just to aid the reader's visualization.

Comment: @goblin Nice idea, thanks! I'll probably leave $e_{i,j}$ to emphasis that these are just elements of the algebra.

Comment: Sorry, this is just wrong. The set of $n\times m$ matrices does not form a ring or an algebra at all when $n\neq m$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, now that I think about it, you're right - but your tone is imo too strong. Its true that, the construction, as given, only works for square matrices, so to claim that it works for all matrices is incorrect; *but*, we can indeed get *all* (finite-size) matrices, essentially by replacing our $R$-algebras with a single [$R$-algebroid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebroid) whose objects are the natural numbers.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Ouch, totally missed that, thank you! I'll fix the answer.

Comment: @goblin: I assume that can be done (but I am not familiar with that notion). But more fundamentally I think there is a mismatch between on one hand what OP asks, which is similar to "how is a map formally defined" (and to which a nuts-and-bolts set-theoretic answer seems appropriate) and on the other hand what this answer provides, which is more similar to an answer to "what structure can be provided by composition of maps" (and which would probably involve category theory).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, I can't really relate to what you're saying. I remember sitting in a combinatorics lecture where they showed us how to use matrices to find the number of paths between two nodes in a digraph of a fixed length $n$. I felt dissatisfied, because the algorithm (which just involves raising the incidence matrix of a digraph $D$ to the power of $n$) didn't list the paths, it just computed the number of paths. So I ran off and invented "generalized matrices" and viola, raising a generalized matrix to the power of $n$ lists all the paths of length $n$. It took me about three days to...

Comment: ...formalize the idea of a generalized matrix, and the way I ended up doing it is by firstly, noticing that matrices can be defined in the way that lisyarus defines them here, and then modifying the definition so that instead of just using the generators $e_{i,j},$ we instead use $e_i, e_{i,j},e_{i,j,k},\ldots$, etc. And instead of identities like $e_{i,j}e_{j,k} = e_{i,k}$, we impose identities like $e_{i,j}e_{j,k} = e_{i,j,k}$. So the mediating "$j$" isn't forgotten, which is what allows "generalized matrices" to 'remember' how they computed their answer. Anyway, ever since that day,..

Comment: ...I've preferred the construction given here.

Comment: @goblin There is also a "nuts and bolts" version of your generalized matrices: Let $E$ be the set of nonempty words on a finite index set $I$. There is a partial monoid operation with $ux\cdot yv$ defined as $uxv$ if $x=y$, where $u,v$ are words and $x,y\in I$. Using [your construction of an algebra from a monoid](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1411608/50776) generalized to partial monoids, this yields an $R$-algebra $M$ over $E$, where the undefined multiplications in $E$ map to $0_M$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro, yes, of course. That was quite literally how I ended up formalizing things: you start with a semigroup $S$ with $0$ and build a semialgebra $\mathbb{N}[S]$. We get different notions of "generalized matrix" for different choices of $S$.

Answer (score 13):

The standard way to define a table of values in some set $S$ as a mathematical object is to encode the positions as an index set $I$, and to represent the table as the map $I\to S$ that associates to each position it value in the table. Then matrices with $n$ rows and $m$ columns and values in $R$ could be represented (taking the usual convention of putting the row index before the column index) as maps $([n]\times[m])\to R$, where $[n]$ is an abbreviation for the $n$-element set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, and "$\times$" denotes the Cartesian product.

However this definition has a drawback that the values $n,m$ cannot always be recovered from a matrix, even though the domain can be recovered from a map. The problem is that $[n]\times[m]=\emptyset$ whenever $n=0$ **or** $m=0$, so for a matrix that is the unique map $\emptyset\to R$, one cannot reconstruct the values of $n,m$. Bourbaki even explicitly states that there is a unique empty matrix, overlooking the fact that this causes problems with definitions that immediately follow in their own presentation. In everyday use of matrices, it is very common to assume that given an $n\times m$ matrix one knows what $n$ and $m$ are, but with the definition of a matrix as a map, this is simply not true in the case of an empty matrix. And empty matrices are necessary for encoding linear maps between finite dimensional vector spaces, in case a vector space of dimension$~0$ is the domain or codomain of the linear map.

One reason this is a real problem is that matrix multiplication is defined in such a way that any product of a $n\times k$ matrix with a $k\times m$ matrix should be an $n\times m$ matrix, each of whose entries is obtained as a sum of $k$ terms. If $k=0$ then both operands of the multiplication are empty matrices, so each entry of the product being a sum of $0$ terms must be $0$, giving the zero matrix of size $n\times m$. However this requires knowing the values of $n$ and $m$, and with the definition of matrix as map, this is not possible. One simply cannot define the product of the unique empty matrix with itself to be a different size zero matrix according to the circumstances.

So the conclusion is that for a rigorous definition of a matrix, one must record the dimensions as components of the matrix itself. So a proper and rigorous definition of a matrix is the following.

> A matrix with entries in $R$ is a triple $(n,m,f)$ where $n,m\in\Bbb N$ and $f$ is a map $([n]\times[m])\to R$.

Comment: An alternative solution rejects the notion of "matrix" in favor of "$n\times m$ matrix", that is, the dimensions must be given as parameters to the definition. (Compare with the definition of "$p$-group", which has $p$ as a parameter.) The matrix multiplication is then parameterized by $n,k,m$, so that $A \cdot_{n,k,m} B$ is defined when $A$ is an $n\times k$ matrix and $B$ is an $k\times n$ matrix, and the result is an $n\times m$ matrix. This simplifies the set theoretic structures at the expense of extra implicit parameters to theorems about matrices.

Comment: ...This is how we resolve this issue in the [Metamath formalization of matrix multiplication](http://us2.metamath.org:88/mpegif/mamuval.html).

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: That might be a solution in certain formal contexts, but has several problems for ordinary mathematical practice. I think what you say is that any matrix _has to_ occur in the context that fixes its size, and cannot be considered on its own. (The analogy with $p$-groups is wobbly: the Klein $4$ group can be studied independently of being a $2$-group.) In practice texts are not written with such a discipline. And it would seem that having a set containing  matrices of different sizes is impossible, contrary to what set theory requires.

Comment: Although I only intended the $p$-group example as a demonstration of "parameterized definition", it is also a good example of this phenomenon. We like to think that we can recover the "$p$" given a $p$-group, and this is *almost* true, but the trivial group is a $p$-group for every $p$, similar to how the empty matrix is a $0\times n$ matrix for every $n$. In almost every case when talking about $p$-groups, though, one is not interested that a group is a $p$ group for some $p$, but rather the specific $p$ used as a parameter to the theorem...

Comment: ... for example in the theorem that a finite $p$-group has size $p^n$ for some $n$, the $p$ in the hypothesis and consequent must match. As for having matrices of different sizes in the same set, this is only done very rarely - a similar sort of thing is the construction of an exterior or tensor algebra, whose elements are linear combination of tensors of different dimension. In this case, the differences are tracked by taking a *disjoint* union of the individual matrix spaces, which effectively adds the "dimension tag" which you are using here.

Comment: That's how I was taught to rigorously define a matrix and it constantly stuns me how it's avoided like HIV even in very careful graduate algebra courses. I've never understood why.

Comment: I would say that even this definition is not general enough because sometimes you want to call something a matrix even if indices do not start from 1

Answer (score 9):

Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers and let $F$ be a field. An $m $ by $n $ matrix with entries in $F $ is a function from $S $ into $F $, where $S $ is the set of all ordered pairs of integers $(i,j) $ such that $1\leq i \leq m  $ and $1\leq j \leq n $.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers define a matrix in a way that is just a rectangular array of numbers. This not only ignores the beauty of the structures, but it makes proving many basic facts (eg. that the determinant is multiplicative, among innumerable others) very cumbersome.

Of course matrices can have very different mathematical structures depending on how you interpret them. (eg. linear transformations, bilinear forms, etc.) Since it's the most common, here's how you could define a matrix as a linear transformation:

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over a field $F$ with respective bases $B$ and $C$. Let $T:V\to W$ be a linear map. Then the "matrix" for $T$ can be defined as the map $B\times C\to F$, which maps $(\beta,\gamma)$ to the coefficient of $T(\beta)$ in the (unique) expansion of $\gamma$ in terms of image of $B$ under $T$, which is a basis for $W$.

Actually it's now obvious how you'd extend this definition to "infinite matrices."

Comment: The question asks what a matrix is, not what matrix should be associated to a linear map. In fact this answer supposes one already knows what a matrix is (the very vaguely mentioned "array representing the map $B\times C\to F$"). Also this definition has the curious consequence that  keeping $T$ but permuting (for instance) the elements of the basis $B$ does not change the matrix at all. Maybe the assumption is that bases are just (unordered) sets. But then one can no longer talk about the first row of a matrix, rather annoying when trying to discuss Gaussian elimination.

Comment: I took out the ambiguous phrase. I think you're missing the point which is that matrices spoken about in mathematics always have some structure, usually a linear map and some choice of basis. No mathematician thinks of a matrix as an arbitrary array of numbers as many of the other answers suggest. By their definitions, a baseball box score is a $2\times12$ matrix, which is silly.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen For uncountably infinite dimensional vector spaces, talking about "the first basis function" or "the first row/column of the matrix" may be meaningless. *Finite* dimensional vector spaces and matrices are a much simpler (but very useful) special case.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how abstract/general/formal you want to get, you might want to check out (google) Chu spaces, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_space Your phrase "array of symbols and expressions" suggests you might want to discuss more abstract arrays than numbers/fields/etc. If the wikipedia page whets your appetite, I'd say the most comprehensive yet easy-to-follow introduction is http://boole.stanford.edu/pub/coimbra.pdf